# Showing a Confirmation on window close in a reactive way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I have an observable that I use for displaying a confirmation dialog, roughly of signature:

```
IObservable<DialogResult> ShowDialog(string title, string message);
```

This shows the user the dialog, with a yes / no button combo.

In my main window, I'm accessing the closing event as such:

```
this.Events().Closing.[Do something here]
```

I want to be able to:

1. Show the confirmation dialog when the closing observable fires
2. Set the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` property to true if the user clicks the "no" button.

I've tried straight-up subscribing:

```
this.Events().Closing.Subscribe(e =>
{
    var res = Dialogs.ShowDialog("Close?", "Really Close?").Wait();
    e.Cancel = res == DialogResult.Ok;
});
```

But that hangs because of the `Wait()` call, I've also tried an async variant:

```
this.Events().Closing.Subscribe(async e =>
{
    var res = await Dialogs.ShowDialog("Close?", "Really Close?");
    e.Cancel = res == DialogResult.Ok;
});
```

Which is no good, because it just returns right away.

What I really want to do is something like:

```
this.Events().Closing.ThenDo(_ => Dialogs.ShowDialog("Close?", "Really Close?"))
    .Subscribe((cancelEventArgs, dialogResult) =>
    {
        cancelEventArgs.Cancel == dialogResult == DialogResult.Ok;
    });
```

But that doesn't exist, I know the key here is in how I **combine** the two observables, but I've no idea how to do so, and the documentation is a little light on practical examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *need* to block the Closing event handler, hence async (or Rx manipulation) won't help you much here.

But you also need to block it in such a way that UI events are still processed, so the UI doesn't freeze.

The most common solution to that is to use Window.ShowDialog instead of Show, and this code works:

```
        this.Events().Closing.Subscribe(e =>
        {
            var ret = new Window().ShowDialog();
            e.Cancel = true;
        });
```

But using that in your ShowDialog Rx method will make its subscribe call block, and that's unlikely what you want (for other cases, in this case it *is* what you need).

Alternatively you can run a inner dispatcher loop, like this:

```
        this.Events().Closing.Subscribe(e =>
        {
            var dialog = Dialogs.ShowDialog("Close?", "Really Close?");
            var dispatcherFrame = new DispatcherFrame();
            dialog.Take(1).Subscribe(res => {
                e.Cancel = res == DialogResult.Ok;
                dispatcherFrame.Continue = false;
            });
            // this will process UI events till the above fires
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(dispatcherFrame);
        });
```

That'll work only if the same Dispatcher is used by both windows.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can avoid blocking by always canceling the close, and closing the form yourself later, which is maybe more Rx-way, i.e.:

```
        var forceClose = default(bool);

        this.Events().Closing
            .Where(_ => !forceClose)
            .Do(e => e.Cancel = true)
            .SelectMany(_ => Dialogs.ShowDialog("Close?", "Really Close?"))
            .Where(res => res == DialogResult.Ok)
            .Do(_ => forceClose = true)
            .Subscribe(_ => this.Close());
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to combine to observable streams is CombineLatest.
This will fire when either one is updated with the last value in each stream.

[Channel 9 video on Combine Latest](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/j.van.gogh/reactive-extensions-api-in-depth-combinelatest)